# ANE-Push-Notification from fresh planet won't fire events

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, push-notification, ane

I'm using push notifications ane for sending local notifications.
But no events are fired. I want to know, is push event got user when app was foreground, so I add event listener:

```
push = PushNotification.getInstance();
push.sendLocalNotification("sd", new Date().time / 1000 + 10, "title");
push.addEventListener(PushNotificationEvent.NOTIFICATION_RECEIVED_WHEN_IN_FOREGROUND_EVENT, function(e:PushNotificationEvent):void {
    trace(e);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the listener before you send the notification?

Comment: of course. tried before and after sending. all events that have in PushNotificationEvent class. I see the push notification on device in notification center, but my game does not.

Comment: you are sending a notification, you are not receiving one.